# Docker cannot find file when building the image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

COPY app/ /app

EXPOSE 8000

RUN cd /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/project/

RUN python manage.py makemigrations
RUN python manage.py migrate
RUN export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project.settings"

CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "server"]
```

When I try to build it, it fails saying that it can't find the requirements.txt inside the app folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
RUN cd /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Docker will enter the /app/project, and then, will come back to the previous folder, then, the second command will fail.
You have to use it like this:

```
RUN cd /app/ && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can visualize how Django works when using Docker on this [link](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/a6b5bb21-48f3-42e9-af3b-50ec7043dc50) that has a container running Django with a similar Dockerfile.

**EDIT**: 
To match a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375372/docker-cannot-find-file-when-building-the-image/45375396#comment77712160_45375396), you should replace the export line to an ENV, example:

```
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project.settings
```

Comment: you should replace `RUN export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="project.settings"` by `ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE project.settings` see the doc for ENV https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Comment: and you should group your RUN, see the Dockerfiles best practices https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: @user2915097 It seems he is still learning Docker. For a newbie, it might be simpler to train, or study, and debug when using separated RUN commands.

Comment: Yes, for example you may understand why sometimes `RUN apt-get update -y RUN apt-get install -y mysoft`  does not work, when it works on the host running docker...  :-) and it works doing `RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y mysoft`